# Traversing a tree-like structure forwards & backwards

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, tree

Im trying to code something very similar to the way I suspect a text adventure game would work, but Im stuck in trying to traverse a tree-like structure in a relatively clean manner. My data structure looks something like this:

```
$survey = [
  'question1' =>  [
    'run' => question1Function;
  ],
  'question2' =>  [
    'run' => question2Function;

    'children' => [
      'pathA': {
        'Question2A1' =>  [
          'run' => question2A1Function;
        ],
        'Question2A2' =>  [
          'run' => question2A2Function;
        ]
      },
      'pathB': {
        'Question2B1' =>  [
          'run' => question2B1Function;
        ]
      }
  ],
  'question3' =>  [
    'run' => question3Function;
  ],
]
```

I would then like to have a `historyManager` of sorts that I can instantiate, passing it the  the `$suvery` above and call `prev()` & `next()` methods on it. In the example above for instance, if question 2 returned `pathA``, it would then ask question2A1 & question2A2 before dropping back to "root" level and asking question 3.

That being said, what makes it complicated (for me at least) is being able to deduce what comes before and after a given node, due to the potentially present levels of nesting/branching (though most I would assume to be no more than 1-2 levels deep).

My first instinct was to add a `$stack = []` to the `historyManager` and push the question itself to the stack once "executed/ran", however, this only answers the `prev()` portion of it.

I could also put a "next", and possibly even a "prev" property on each question:

```
$survey = [
  'question1' =>  [
    'run' => question1Function;
    'next' => ['question2']
  ],
  'question2' =>  [
    'run' => question2Function;
    // Could possibly take different paths
    'next' => ['pathA', 'pathB', 'question3']
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way or if I'm going about this all wrong. Surely someone knows better & I appreciate any help I can get. This is written in pseudocode-ish style as I'm still trying to wrap my head around it and don't have an actual implementation. However my idea of the `historyManager` would be something like this:

```
historyManager($survey) {
  $stack = [];

  prev() {
    // Remove current question from stack
    // & repeat previous entry
  }

  next() {
    // Fetch the next question, execute, &
    // push to stack
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but could you make your question clearer? I believe the stack you proposed is capable of fullfilling your requirement. What problem have you encountered? What else do you need?

Comment: @simonmysun Thank you for your input. I was merely seeing how someone more experienced might approach the same problem and or if there was simply a better way of keeping track of where I am on the tree (perhaps even able to drop the `'next => ['nextKey']'` portion out of the question). Im still researching, but I guess I will continue with this approach unless I come across something better.

Comment: I would suggest dopping the hierarchical structure in your array and represent the tree with a flat list of nodes with their parent / children information. Then a simple pre-order tree traversal with conditions is enough. The stack is necessary and might be implictly used in the pre-order tree traversal.

Comment: Consider using DS extension. There are structures better than array to perform game i.e stack, queues. https://github.com/php-ds/ext-ds

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll take a look at it!